# How to auto resize grid columns based on the data in Kendo-Angular2-grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using the plunker mentioned at Telerik's web page:
http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/

I tried changing column width to auto but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ColumnComponent/#toc-width) currently kendo grid column supports only width specified in pixels:

> **width**
>
> The width of the column in pixels.

However if you won't provide this property for one or mores column it will take all remaning space (equally divided if more than one).

So if you want for column to be auto width just skip this property in its definition.